# Django db average of a DateTimeField

Tags: django, django-models

I need to compute the average datetime of a table and I am using aggregate with Avg but it returns a float type number and not a datetime object. What exactly does this float number represent?

And, most importantly, how do I convert it to a datetime object?

Comment: can you show an example ?

Comment: examples are goooood (both code and output etc)

Answer (score 1):

For further reference, I had to deal with a similar problem. Considering the models:

```
class Championship(models.Model):
    ...

class Game(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    championship = models.ForeignKey(Championship)
```

Some games are related to a championship, and I wanted, from this championship to return an average value of the dates of the games, for example if I have one game on January 1st and one game on January 3rd, I wanted to return January 2nd.

On a postgresql background, the naive use of the built-in Avg to make an aggregate did not work : (because Avg has not been designed for datetime fields)

```
>>> championship.game_set.aggregate(Avg('date'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "~/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 158, in aggregate
    return self.get_query_set().aggregate(*args, **kwargs)
  File "~/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 359, in aggregate
    return query.get_aggregation(using=self.db)
  File "~/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 389, in get_aggregation
    result = query.get_compiler(using).execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "~/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 840, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "~/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 41, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "~/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 58, in execute
    six.reraise(utils.DatabaseError, utils.DatabaseError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "~/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 54, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
DatabaseError: function avg(date) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT AVG("games_game"."date") AS "date__avg" FROM "games_g...
           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

So I tried two solutions, one using django querysets and python, the second one using mostly raw SQL.

```
def compute_avg_date(self):
    """                                                                                                                           
    Return the average date of the championship's game set.
    Casts dates into time deltas, in order to perform a python mean.
    """
    game_set = self.game_set.values_list('date', flat=True)
    origin_date = datetime.date.min
    try:
        return (
            sum(
                map(lambda date: date-origin_date, game_set),
                datetime.timedelta(0))/len(game_set) + origin_date)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return datetime.date.today()

def compute_avg_date_db(self):
    """                                                                                                                           
    Does the same as above but directly in db operations.
    """
    try:
        return self.game_set.filter(week=week).extra(
            select={
                'avg_time': 'to_timestamp(avg(extract(epoch from date)))'
                }).values_list(
            'avg_time', flat=True)[0].date()
    except AttributeError:
        return datetime.date.today()
```

I thought the db-only version would have been faster so I did a little testbench.

```
>>> s = """\
... from championships.models import Championship
... champ = Championship.objects.get(pk=1)
... champ.compute_avg_date_db(10)
... """
>>> s1 = """\
... from championships.models import Championship
... champ = Championship.objects.get(pk=1)
... champ.compute_avg_date(10)
... """
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=s, number=1000)
8.195073127746582
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=s1, number=1000)
6.377335071563721
```

I did some other similar test, all of them were showing that the compute_avg_date method, i.e. the method using django querysets and python is slightly faster than the raw SQL method. I am not a specialist so if anyone can explain it, remarks are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Having just run a test on a model of my own, it appears to be the average of the year